# Find callback functions added with jQuery on DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, callback

I am currently testing this in Mozilla FireFox 3.0.5 using FireBug 1.3.0 with jQuery 1.2.6.

### First try

```
document.getElementById("x").onfocus = function ()
{
    var helloWorld = "Hello World";
};
```

**FireBug console:**

document.getElementById("helloworld").onfocus.toString() **= function body as a string**

$("#helloworld").get(0).onfocus.toString() **= function body as a string**

---

### Second try

```
$("#helloworld").focus(function ()
{
    var helloWorld = "Hello World";
});
```

**FireBug console:**

document.getElementById("helloworld").onfocus.toString() **= FireBug returns nothing**

$("#helloworld").get(0).onfocus.toString() **= FireBug returns nothing**

---

What am I missing here? Why can't I find the callbacks when attaching them with jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To view events that jQuery has bound use :

```
$("#helloworld").data('events');
```

If you bind the focus as per your example and you run the above in firebug console  it will return

```
Object focus=Object
```

Comment: Yeah, this was 4 yes ago:) This things change!

Comment: I probably could've done a better job of making this clear, but that whole comment is a link to a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJZBU/). I was hoping you might make it work?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery doesn't attach the callbacks directly, instead it stores them internally in a registry.  Whenever an event is triggered, jQuery looks in the registry and calls the callback that you asked for earlier.

This gives you the advantage of being able to stack multiple callbacks onto a single element's event, but it has the disadvantage that you **must** use jQuery's event handler routines to set, get, and remove the callbacks.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on the event-registry on the jQuery site. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  The Jquery website primarily describes the objects and interfaces used, it doesn't get into the internals of how they accomplished it very much.  If you look at the jQuery source at where events are bound, you'll see what they are doing.

Comment: (that's what I did when I became curious :)